# Detailed Output of a cumulative incidence function in R

Tags: r, competing-risks

I will preface this by saying I am not a trained statistician, so please be gentle. I am using R to construct a cumulative incidence function curve for a single-arm evaluation at multiple timepoints of interest. The outcomes of interest is 'Event' with 'Death' as a competing risk (and the third option being 'censored'). I have used the 'tidycmprsk' package, with the 'cuminc' function to create the curve (code below). My colaborators request that I output, for each timepoint in the analysis, the cumulative incidence (and 95% CI), and number of patients who have had an event, been censored, or are still eligible. The output (tidyCumInc) gives me some information at set timepoints, but not the number of events. Is anyone aware of a was I can get out the output I am desiring?

Thanks so much for your time in advance.
Bill

── cuminc() ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

• Failure type "Death"
time    n.risk   estimate   std.error   95% CI
500     2,507    0.250      0.005       0.240, 0.260
1,000   633      0.369      0.007       0.356, 0.382
1,500   163      0.432      0.008       0.416, 0.447
2,000   54       0.456      0.009       0.439, 0.473
2,500   18       0.465      0.009       0.447, 0.483
3,000   6        0.480      0.011       0.458, 0.501

• Failure type "Outcome"
time    n.risk   estimate   std.error   95% CI
500     2,507    0.260      0.005       0.250, 0.270
1,000   633      0.382      0.007       0.368, 0.395
1,500   163      0.439      0.008       0.424, 0.455
2,000   54       0.469      0.009       0.451, 0.486
2,500   18       0.495      0.010       0.475, 0.514
3,000   6        0.495      0.010       0.475, 0.514

```
## Cumulative incidence function using 'tidycmprsk' package
library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggsurvfit)

tidyCumInc <- cuminc(Surv(Time, Event) ~ 1,
                     data = DATA_TEST,
                     rho = 0)
tidyCumInc

# Plot CIF curve
cuminc(Surv(Time, Event) ~ 1, data = DATA_TEST, rho = 0) %>%
  ggcuminc() +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable()
```

[image]